# Paginación y Eventos con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, c#, eventos, blazor

estoy trabajando en una pagina antigua y tienen una funcion para crear un scroll infinito, esto genera que al momento de buscar algo lanze los primeros 40 resultados, al llegar al final de la pagina se hace la peticion de nuevo y se renderizan los siguientes 40 resultados, cada resultado es un item que tiene un boton "Agregar al Carrito" y lo tengo enlazado con una funcion a un archivo jquery de esta forma:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#@Html.Raw("btn-add-car-" + part.partId)").btnaddcart();
});
```

El detalle que tengo es que al hacer la primer carga todos lo botones tienen ese event registrado pero al hacer la paginación los siguientes 40 ya no lo tienen por consecuente marcar un error de que .btnaddcart() no es una función.

Alguien sabe como puedo resolverlo?
Les agradezco su ayuda, gracias de antemano:).

Comment: Agrega la función JS que realiza la carga de los datos, porque es ahí donde debes aplicar la corrección

Comment: El sitio no es mío, estoy dándole mantenimiento, como pude observar su comportamiento es que la lista de items es una lista parcial que se renderiza dentro de otra vista parcial y esas dos combinadas se renderizan en otra vista que es un layout con todo el código, esta función la agrego en la primer vista, seria agregar ese funcionamiento en la misma función del scroll verdad?

Comment: mmm mas o menos. En la función donde recibes los nuevos datos (que no se si te llegan como json o como html), vas a tener que agregar el evento al botón. Pero así como está tu pregunta es difícil dar más detalle, por ejemplo a mi me parece que extraño `$("#@Html.Raw("btn-add-car-" + part.partId)").btnaddcart();` ya que eso agrega el evento a **UN** solo botón y no a los primero 40

Comment: Exacto, el caso es que esa vista parcial llega a otra median un VDD y hace un RenderPartial, esa vista se repite 40 veces, y cada vista tiene un botón ósea 40 botones en total, pero al momento de hacer la siguiente iteración ósea del 41 en adelante los botones ya no contienen ese event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advertencia: Esta no es la mejor opción, pero para que tengas una solución mientras encuentras una mejor

---

Yo siempre recomiendo para estos casos usar el atributo `onclick` (aquí hay otros desarrolladores que no están de acuerdo). Pero es que justamente cuando renderizas contenido dinámicamente el manejo de los eventos es un lio.

Yo en tu caso, para solventar el problema de forma rápida, crearía una función:

```
function UnaFuncion(){
  const hasEvent = $._data(event.target, "events")?.click?.length;
  if(!hasEvent){
    $(event.target).btnaddcart();
    event.target.click();   
  }
}
```

Esta función lo que hace es evaluar si el elemento tiene un evento `click`, si no lo tiene lo agrega y realiza automáticamente el click.

Luego en tu vista parcial donde están los botones en HTML, agrego el atributo `onclik`

```
<button onclick="UnaFuncion()">
```

DEMO:

Aquí a `boton1` le agregamos el evento de forma predeterminada (representa los primero 40 botones), y `boton2` representa desde el botón #41 en adelante

```js
//función de ejemplo para simular lo que hace "btnaddcart"
$.fn.btnaddcart = function(){
  this.click( () => console.log("HOLA"));
  return this;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    //Ejemplo donde solo agregamos el evento a 1 botón
    $("#boton1").btnaddcart();
});

function UnaFuncion(){
  const hasEvent = $._data(event.target, "events")?.click?.length;
  if(!hasEvent){
    $(event.target).btnaddcart();
    event.target.click();   
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="boton1" onclick="UnaFuncion()">Botón 1</button>
<button id="boton2" onclick="UnaFuncion()">Botón 2</button>
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte amigo, lamentablemente no encontre solucion para el problema, la funcion `.btnaddcart();` pertenece a un archivo jquery y es algo asi:
`if (jQuery) {
    (function ($) {
        $.fn.extend({
            btnaddcart: function (options) {
                var settings = {
                    action: "click",
                    prefix: ""
                };
                $.extend(settings, options);`
a como interprete el error, se produce por que en la paginacion ya no carga JQuery, por lo tanto no entra a esa funcion y marca que `.btnaddcart()` no esta definida